# Show tooltip on image icon click

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have many image icon on my page which have Tooltip on it and show different text in tooltip. I want to show each tooltips when user click on its image icon not on hover. and also when user click on any other place or area of page tooltip also hide or disappear.

```
<img style="width:26px; height: 23px;" class="customTooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="" src="/images/alert.png" data-original-title="Number Typ and Service Type:">
```

Comment: Provide a code so that we can know your progress and help you.

Comment: Please include all relevant code.

Comment: I have added code. please review it and help me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using bootstrap

```
 <b-button id="tooltip-target-1">
    Click Me
  </b-button>
  <b-tooltip target="tooltip-target-1" triggers="click">
    I am tooltip <b>component</b> content!
  </b-tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel. You can use third party library like [TippyJs](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/):

```js
tippy(".item", {
  trigger: 'click',
  content: `item info`,
  allowHTML: true,
  animation: 'fade',
  onShow(instance) {
    let element = instance.reference;
    instance.setContent(element.getAttribute('data-info'));
    //console.log(instance);
  },
});
```

```css
img {
  margin: 2rem
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@6"></script>
<img class='item' src="https://picsum.photos/id/4/150/100" data-info="item info 1">
<img class='item' src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/150/100" data-info="item info 2">
```

Answer (score 0):

My JQuery solution without any other js libs for custom tooltip:

```js
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var noHideTooltip = false;
        $(document).click(function(e) {
            if (!noHideTooltip) {
                $('.tooltip-box-show').removeClass('tooltip-box-show');
            }
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.tooltip-box', function(e) {
            $('.tooltip-box-show').removeClass('tooltip-box-show');
            $(this).addClass('tooltip-box-show');
            noHideTooltip = true;
            setTimeout(function() { noHideTooltip = false; }, 0);
        });
    });
  </script>
```

```css
.tooltip-text {display:none; background:#ccc;}
.tooltip-box-show ~ .tooltip-text {display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4e/OOjs_UI_icon_alert_destructive.svg/120px-OOjs_UI_icon_alert_destructive.svg.png" class="tooltip-box"><span class="tooltip-text">Text here..</span
```

Just add your css tooltip style